# How to translate a library's doxygen \mainpage into a \page?

Tags: doxygen

I have a library which is documented using doxygen which is used within a larger project. **I have a nice \mainpage for my library which I would like to be demoted to a \page when I am running doxygen on the larger project. Is there an easy way to do this without relying on tools other than those installed by Doxygen?** To illustrate, when when running doxygen on the library by itself doxygen should see:

```
/**    
\mainpage

\section main_introduction Introduction

The Gen-MC (Generalised Monte-Carlo) simulation tool.
*/
```

And when I run doxygen in the larger project it should see:

```
/**    
\page gen_MC_mainpage Gen-MC

\section main_introduction Introduction

The Gen-MC (Generalised Monte-Carlo) simulation tool.
*/
```

I assume I could use INPUT_FILTER and a perl script to do this but the more tools I have to get people to install to generate the documentation the less likely they are to make use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using conditions

```
/**    
\if USEMAINPAGE
\mainpage
\else
\page gen_MC_mainpage Gen-MC
\endif

\section main_introduction Introduction

The Gen-MC (Generalised Monte-Carlo) simulation tool.
*/
```

In your smaller project's Doxyfile add USEMAINPAGE as an enabled section:

```
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = USEMAINPAGE
```

[if command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdif)  for more info.